# why does my code only check the first letter of the word in my hangman game(c++)?

Tags: c++

this is my hangman game as it stands, i am sorry for any junior mistakes made in this code.

```
#include <iostream>         
#include <Windows.h>        
#include <fstream> 
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    system ("CLS");
    system("COLOR FC");
    std::cout<<"\t\t#     #                      #     #              "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t#     #   ##   #    #  ####  ##   ##   ##   #    #"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t#     #  #  #  ##   # #    # # # # #  #  #  ##   #"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t####### #    # # #  # #      #  #  # #    # # #  #"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t#     # ###### #  # # #  ### #     # ###### #  # #"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t#     # #    # #   ## #    # #     # #    # #   ##"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t#     # #    # #    #  ####  #     # #    # #    #"<<std::endl;
    Sleep (3000);
    system ("CLS");
    char word [128];

    int a=0;
    do
        {
            system ("CLS");
            switch (a % 5)
                {
                case 0:
                    std::cout<<"loading..."<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    std::cout<<"loading.."<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    std::cout<<"loading."<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    std::cout<<"loading.."<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    std::cout<<"loading..."<<std::endl; 
                    break;
                }
            Sleep (50);
            ++a;
        }
    while (a < 50);

    system ("CLS"); 
    std::cout<<"\t \t \t Welcome to my Hangman game"<<std::endl;    // start of game 
    Sleep (2500);
    system ("CLS");
    std::cout<<"\t \t \t \t Here are the rules"<<std::endl; 
    Sleep (2500);
    system ("CLS"); 
    std::cout<<"\t You will have six lives in order to guess the letters within a word"<<std::endl;
    Sleep (2500);
    system ("CLS"); 
    std::cout<<"\t \t After all of your lives have been used up you lose"<<std::endl;
    Sleep (2500);
    system ("CLS"); 
    std::cout<<"\t \t \t \t  Good luck"<<std::endl;
    Sleep (2500);
    system ("CLS"); 

    int game;                       // press key to continue 
    std::cout<<"\t \t Do you wish to play"<<std::endl<<"\t \t Press 1 to play or press any other key to exit"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> game;

    if (game = 1)                   // code for game 
        {
            system ("CLS");
            std::cout<<"\t \t You have chosen to play hangman \n"<<"\t \t Good luck"<<std::endl;


            int randnum;                    //random number generator (co developed with jeremy dyer) 

            srand(time(NULL));

            randnum = rand() % 10000 + 1;


            std::ifstream ifs("words.txt");             //search text file for a word within the file 
            char temp[128];
            while(!ifs.eof() && (randnum > 0))
                {
                    ifs >> temp; 
                    --randnum; 
                }
            strcpy_s (word, temp);              //temp to word not word to temp     

            int lives = 6;                  // set amount of lives 

            char guess;                     // declare  guess 

            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)     //checking letter input against the word 
                {
                    char c = word[i];               
                    if(c == 0)
                        {
                            continue;                   
                        }

                    std::cout<< word; // help with testing (so i can see what word has been picked)

                    while ( lives >0)
                        {

                            std::cout<<"\t \t please enter your guess"<<std::endl;
                            std::cin>> guess;

                            if (guess == c)
                                {
                                    system("CLS");
                                    std::cout<<"that is correct"<<std::endl; 
                                    std::cout<<" you have "<< lives<<" remaining"<<std::endl; 
                                }

                            else 
                                {
                                    system("CLS");
                                    lives --;
                                    std::cout<<" bad luck that is wrong"<<std::endl;
                                    std::cout<<" you have "<< lives<<" remaining"<<std::endl;
                                }
                        }

                    if (lives <= 0)
                        {
                            system("CLS");
                            std::cout<<" Sorry you lose"<<std::endl<<" Please try again"<<std::endl;
                            std::cin.get();
                            return 0;
                        }
                }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

once again i appreciate any help sorting this problem out.
if you do reply to this question please try to be patient with me i have been at this very long

Comment: love the debugger and it shall love you back.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stack overflow. You should be posting a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is a lot of code that is not needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You should read the guess and then loop over the letters in the word, not ask for a guess inside the loop.

Comment: sorry bolov i have been awake for a while trying to get this assignment done, and Barmar can you expand that as i said i have been up for a long time and i pretty much only living off caffeine at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, your code is doing this:

```
for letter in word:
  while lives > 0:
    read guess
    if guess == letter:
      ...
    else:
      ...
    if lives = 0:
      end game
  end while
end for
```

You want it to do this instead:

```
while lives > 0:
  read guess
  for letter in word:
    if guess == letter:
      ...
  end for
  if no match was found:
    lives = lives - 1
end while
```

Currently you are looping through your word in the outermost loop. You need to loop through the entire word on every guess.

Comment: ah i see, thanks for this its a massive help :)

Comment: thank you for your help, i have worked a little, i now checks the whole word but if i enter an incorrect value and then try to enter a correct one it says its still incorrect

Comment: Right. It's impossible to know what might be wrong without seeing your code, but if you're using some kind of variable to keep track of whether the guess was incorrect, maybe you're forgetting to reset it on each new guess?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i rewrote some of my code and found the problem thank you very much for your help